# Why import complicated stl file will caused problem on gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My cad translate to stl file is
[image: image description]

I use meshlab to view it:

[image: image description]

But when I import to gazebo.

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/stl$ rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file      `pwd`/foot.urdf -urdf -model foot_model -z 100.5
 loading model xml from file
 attempting to spawn robot in simulation
 waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
 spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
 spawning success True
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/stl$
```

The model seems very weird even broken to parts.

[image: image description]

How to solve it? Thank you~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10893/why-import-complicated-stl-file-will-caused-problem-on-gazebo?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-21**:
I have added the picture in meshlab, and I also upload the stl file:    http://www.adrive.com/public/8796d1359372a369f97531afc9a972ad728f8e47d46b8746e2a3242b27619be4.html

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-15**:
you can try and import the stl file with some other mesh editors such as meshlab or wings3d (or blender if the top image was not a stl import).  If things look ok there, can you post the STL file?  thanks.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-15**:
Single STL. I haven't tried Multiple STL's connected by joints.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-15**:
Hi Sam, is this a single STL?  Multiple STL's connected by joints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the mesh contains faces that are not 2-manifolds.  I recommend shrink-wrapping the mesh with one of the modern cad packages.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-25**:
Autodesk Inventor Professional 2012.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-24**:
what software are you using to generate STL from CAD model?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-24**:
I already use the smallest resolution option of stl export.Is there any other way to shrink-wrapping the mesh? Or how to import it to gazebo correctly?